# How to use dark mode on aws console?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am experimenting with the console, as I have to sit down for extended hours using it, so I thought to use it in dark mode. Does anybody know how to do it without cookie modification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update 21st Oct 2022: For All AWS Resources to support Dark Mode. Do the following in the Unified Settings

- Login to http://console.aws.amazon.com
- in the top right corner, click on your **user@aws_account_number**,
- Go to **Settings-> Display -> Edit -> Visual Mode** or go to https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/settings/home
- Choose your preferred visual mode. The dark mode might not apply across all AWS service consoles.
- Save Settings

Another way, with Chrome, you can do it in the following ways via the cookie, log into the AWS console first.. then:

- In Chrome, go to Chrome **Developer Tools**
- Go to **Application -> Storage -> Cookies** then expand the cookies section and there will be the console URL that you are on like
  https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-east-1.
- Click the console URL and it will show you all the attributes associated.
- Look for '**awsc-color-theme**' the value should be '**light**'.
- Change the value to '**dark**'.
- Now refresh the AWS console and you'll see it in dark mode Enjoy!

Update 04 Oct 2022: AWS has changed the cookie name from '**aws-color-theme**' to '**awsc-color-theme**'. After this hack, the services that would be available in the dark mode with the console are following, AWS is continuously developing in this direction. As of this time, when the console session expires, which usually happens I think in 12 hours, the cookies in the developer panel will reset to default **light**.

**Compute**

- AWS Batch
- AWS Outposts
- EC2 Image Builder
- AWS App Runner

**Containers**

- ECR
- ECS New Experience
- Red Hat OpenShift Service on AWS (ROSA)

**Storage**

- EFS
- Storage Gateway
- AWS Backup
- AWS Elastic Disaster Recovery

**Database**

- Amazon ElastiCache
- Amazon DocumentDB
- Amazon Timestream
- DynamoDB
- Amazon MemoryDB for Redis

**Migration & Transfer**

- AWS Application Migration Service
- AWS Database Migration Service
- AWS Transfer Family
- AWS Snow Family
- AWS DataSync
- AWS Mainframe Modernization

**Networking & Content Delivery**

- AWS App Mesh
- AWS Cloud Map
- AWS Global Accelarator
- Amazon VPC IP Address Manager
- AWS Private 5G

**Developer Tools**

- AWS FIS

**Customer Enablement**

- AWS Activate

**Robotics**

- AWS RoboMaker

**Blockchain**

- Amazon Managed Blockchain

**Satellite**

- AWS Ground Station

**Quantum Technologies**

- Amazon Braket

**Management & Governance**

- AWS Organizations
- Trusted Advisor
- AWS Control Tower
- AWS License Manager
- AWS Well-Architected Tool
- AWS Chatbot
- AWS Compute Optimizer
- Amazon Managed Grafana
- Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus
- AWS Proton
- AWS Resilience Hub
- Incident Manager

**Media Services**

- Amazon Kinesis Video Streams
- AWS Elemental MediaConnect
- AWS Elemental MediaConvert
- AWS Elemental MediaPackage
- AWS Elemental MediaStore
- AWS Elemental MediaTailor
- AWS Elemental Appliances & Software
- Amazon Interactive Video Service
- Amazon Nimble Studio

**Machine Learning**

- Amazon CodeGuru
- Amazon DevOps Guru
- Amazon Comprehend
- Amazon Comprehend Medical
- Amazon Fraud Detector
- Amazon Kendra
- Amazon Personalize
- Amazon Rekognition
- Amazon Textract
- Amazon Transcribe
- Amazon Translate
- Amazon Lex
- AWS DeepComposer
- AWS DeepLens
- AWS DeepRacer
- AWS Panorama
- Amazon Monitron
- Amazon HealthLake
- Amazon Lookout for Vision
- Amazon Lookout for Equipment
- Amazon Lookout for Metrics

**Analytics**

- Amazon Athena
- Amazon EMR Serverless
- Amazon CloudSearch (New Console)
- Amazon Kinesis
- AWS Glue
- AWS Lake Formation
- Amazon Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (Amazon MSK)
- Amazon FinSpace

**Security, Identity, & Compliance**

- AWS Resource Access Manager
- Amazon Cognito (New Console)
- AWS GuardDuty
- Amazon Inspector
- Amazon Macie
- AWS Key Management Service
- AWS CloudHSM
- Amazon Detective
- AWS Signer
- AWS Audit Manager

**AWS Cost Management**

- AWS Marketplace
- AWS Billing Conductor

**Front-end Web & Mobile**

- AWS AppSync
- Device Farm
- Amazon Location Service

**AR & VR**

- Amazon Sumerian

**Application Integration**

- AWS Step Functions
- Amazon AppFlow
- Amazon EventBridge
- Amazon MQ
- Amazon Simple Workflow (SWF) (New Console)
- Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow (MWAA)

**Business Applications**

- Amazon Connect
- Amazon Honeycode
- Amazon SES (New Console)
- Amazon WorkDocs
- Amazon WorkMail

**End User Computing**

- WorkSpaces Web

**Internet of Things**

- AWS IoT RoboRunner
- AWS IoT TwinMaker
- AWS IoT FleetWise

**Game Development**

- Amazon GameSparks

Comment: It didn't work, refreshed with Ctl+R, and also new tabs, remains light mode in the ec2 pages for example. I switched to "all services" and it seems like menu is dark mode now, but trying in s3 and ec2 pages it's light. Also the cookie name is "awsc-color-theme" with 'c' :)

Comment: Hi Mr. Dmitry Shmakov, see the updated answer now.

Comment: it works in some services, indeed! thanks

Comment: Didn't find a way to make it work for federated user though...

Answer (score 0):

Just change the settings from the Accounts menu at the top right.